# Объединить две таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 4 таблицы:

- User
- User_shipper
- Info_user
- Info_user_shipper

Таблица `user` – список пользователей_1
Таблица `user_shipper` – список пользователей_2
Таблица `info_user` – информация о пользователей_1. Связь с user.
Таблица `info_user_shipper` – информация о пользователей_2. Связь с user_shipper.

Нужно таблицу `User_shipper` и `info_user_shipper` объединить с `user` и `Info_user` соответсвенно.

Но есть одна загвоздка. User Дает объявления в одну категорию. `User_shipper` в другую.

Объявления связано с ключем `id_user`  и `id_user_shipper` с таблицами `user` и `user_shipper`. Чтобы понимать кто дал объявление.

Так вот, как бесполезнено это все перенести?
Нужен алгоритм

Comment: left join объединять если поле может быть не заполнено. более ничего из вопроса не ясно что куда переносить собственно. И структура таблиц странная. Если их роли настолько похожи и приходится давать ссылки то на одно то на другое - то с вероятностью 90% - это одна и та же сущность. Т.е. любые пользователи должны быть в одной таблице users, просто вводите им поле "категория" что бы отличать одних от других

Comment: Отрисуйте на бумаге связи - будет понятно где join ставить. Нарисуйте нам символами | в code связи полей слева названия таблиц - а дальше в ряд список их полей. т.е  `User   id  field2` и т д. Или таки картинку связей